# How to convert binary back to normal string?

Tags: c#, char

So I have this:

```
char x = 'a';
int number = (int)x;

textBox.Text = number.ToString(); // actual "97", wanted "a"
```

It will display `"97"` if I print it.
How can I convert this back to char `'a'`?
I tried a lot of things but it always displays **97**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert first to `char` (you'll get `'a'` from ascii code `97`) and only then to `string` (`"a"`):

```
textBox.Text = ((char)number).ToString();
```

Same idea but with implicit `ToString()` which will be called by string interpolation:

```
textBox.Text = $"{(char)number}";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [System.Convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert?view=netcore-3.1):

```
char x = 'a';
int number = (int)x;
char chrNumber = System.Convert.ToChar(number);
textBox.text = chrNumber.ToString();
```